# XML to CSV using xslt - handling missing elements with blank

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I'm trying to create generic xslt for XML to CSV.

Facing issues when elements not available in particular child doesn't produce blank value and if the node

Is it possible to achieve generic xslt for for different xmls which has similar tree structure with only difference in element nodes

Root- Child - Element1,Element2
      Child - Element3
      Child - Element4

Sample input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryResponse>

  <User>
    <Id>rti</Id>

  </User>
  <User>
    <Id>qwe</Id>
    <EmployeeNumber>emp1</EmployeeNumber>
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Id>Abc</Id>
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <EmployeeNumber>emp4</EmployeeNumber>
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>

  </User>
</queryResponse>
```

Expected Output

```html
"Id","EmployeeNumber","IsActive"
"rti","",""
"qwe","emp1","false"
"Abc","","false"
"123","emp4","false"
```

Tried XSLT

```html
   
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" /><!-- xA = NL, xD = CR -->
<xsl:param name="colnames" select="'y'"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />


<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<!--headerline-->
<xsl:if test="$colnames = 'y'">
 <!-- <xsl:if test="position() = 1"> -->
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
 <xsl:text>"</xsl:text> 
 <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
 <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>  
             <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
             </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <!-- hardcode version newline -->
 <!--<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>-->
      <!-- linebreak, nicer -->
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
<!--  </xsl:if>  -->
</xsl:if>


<!--dataline-->
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">

<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text> 
   <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="position()  = last()">
 <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
 <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
</xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resulted output

```html
"Id"
"rti"
"qwe","emp1","false"
"Abc","false"
"123","emp4","false"
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this please 'Facing issues when elements not available in particular child doesn't produce blank value and if the node'. It is not very clear what is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to define or detect the unique column names (i.e. third level element names) and then process each second level element to check whether it has such a column and if not output an empty string instead.

If you are not confined to XSLT 1 but could use XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 or Altova 2017/2018 or Exselt 1.1) you can do that in a compact way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="lf" as="xs:string" select="'&#10;'"/>
  <xsl:param name="quote" as="xs:string" select="'&quot;'"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:quote" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="$quote || replace($input, $quote, '$0$0') || $quote"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:param name="cols" as="xs:QName*" select="distinct-values(/*/*/*/node-name())"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="$cols!mf:quote(string())" separator="{$sep}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:value-of select="for $col in $cols return mf:quote((*[node-name() eq $col], '')[1])" separator="{$sep}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhr.

And XSLT 2 version is at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/bFukv8h, it simply uses `for .. return ..` instead of `!` and `concat` instead of `||`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="lf" as="xs:string" select="'&#10;'"/>
  <xsl:param name="quote" as="xs:string" select="'&quot;'"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:quote" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="concat($quote, replace($input, $quote, '$0$0'), $quote)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:param name="cols" as="xs:QName*" select="distinct-values(/*/*/*/node-name(.))"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="for $col in $cols return mf:quote(string($col))" separator="{$sep}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:value-of select="for $col in $cols return mf:quote((*[node-name(.) eq $col], '')[1])" separator="{$sep}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$lf"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin , thanks for your answer it works as expected but my framework supports XSLT 2.0 and doesnt allow use of external function like mf. how to make this code adhere to those restrictions

Comment: XSLT 2 supports `xsl:function` so I am not sure why you mention XSLT 2 but then tell us that user-defined functions are not possible. Please clarify. I have edited the answer and added an XSLT 2 version, but still using a function. If for some reasons you can't do that you will have to replace all function calls to that function with the code in the function body.

Comment: Thanks Martin , works with XSLT 2.0 ...earlier we had issue while using exsl:node-set() function stating External function calls have been disabled.